# How to programatically create functions for Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-log-analytics-workspace

The [Functions in Azure Monitor log queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/functions) doc explains how to create functions in Log Analytics workspace manually, but doesn't explain how to do it automatically. What is the recommended way of doing it?

I tried to use [.create-or-alter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-alter-function) from Kusto.Explorer but it didn't work (I have correct connection, as I can execute existing functions and read data). The documentation section on [function supportability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data#function-supportability) doesn't mention support for it, so no surprise here.

I did discover [find or update saved searches API method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/saved-searches/create-or-update) that seems promising. But calling API directly is nowhere near as convenient as executing `.create-or-alter function` from my Kusto.Explorer.

Is there an easier way to create functions programmatically? If there is an SDK support for it, could I get links to the relevant methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this comment on GitHub issues I opened, titled 'The "Functions in Azure Monitor log queries" doc doesn't explain what is the recommended programmatic way of creating functions #94841'](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/94841#issuecomment-1180487440)
`guywi-ms` replied:

> There are SDKs that you can use to create functions programmatically, including:
>
> C# SDK:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.operationalinsights.models.savedsearch?view=azure-dotnet
>
> Python SDK:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-loganalytics/azure.mgmt.loganalytics.models.savedsearch?view=azure-python